# Jquery Orgchart- Display all nodes one by one with slide down animation after page load completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, orgchart, getorgchart

I want to display all nodes one by one with  **expanding animation** after page load completes.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fully-Customizable-Organisational-Chart-Plugin-With-jQuery-OrgChart/

I tried this way but not working.

```js
var oc = $('#chart-container').orgchart({
  'data': datascource,
  'depth': 1,
  'nodeTitle': 'name',
  'nodeContent': 'title',
  'nodeID': 'id',
  'createNode': function($node, data) {
    var nodePrompt = $('<i>', {
      'class': 'fa fa-info-circle second-menu-icon',
      click: function() {
        $(this).siblings('.second-menu').toggle();
      }
    });
    var secondMenu = '<div class="second-menu"><img class="avatar" src="img/avatar/' + data.id + '.jpg"></div>';
    $node.append(nodePrompt).append(secondMenu);
  },
  'direction': 'b2t'
});


oc.$chart.find('.node').each("pageload", function() {
  oc.showChildren($(this));
});
```

Comment: Can you please link directly to the OrgChart library page and its documentation, not the 'jQuery scrips' leech site.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Seems to be [this](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart), based on the [demo](https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/ajax-datasource.html), at least.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's displaying all the node at once. but I need animation like smooth sliding down (like when we clicking on any node that will expand child nodes with slow motion.)